# Error while deploying on cloud using cloud foundry

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I have installed **cloud foundry plugin** on my grails project and I have successfully pushed my project once onto the cloud but when I tried to update my app using,

```
grails prod cf-update
```

command. When I did this, I get the following error:

```
ERROR - Application 'scheduleNew' failed to start, logs information below. 

==== logs/stderr.log ==== 
Jan 23, 2012 2:45:02 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init 
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8963 
Jan 23, 2012 2:45:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load 
INFO: Initialization processed in 378 ms 
Jan 23, 2012 2:45:02 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm setContainer 
INFO: Set JAAS app name Catalina 
Jan 23, 2012 2:45:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start 
INFO: Starting service Catalina 
Jan 23, 2012 2:45:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start 
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 
Jan 23, 2012 2:45:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory 
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT 
Jan 23, 2012 2:45:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start 
SEVERE: Error listenerStart 
Jan 23, 2012 2:45:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start 
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors 
Jan 23, 2012 2:45:12 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads 
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. 
Jan 23, 2012 2:45:12 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads 
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@7e628e42] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. 
Jan 23, 2012 2:45:12 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads 
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [org.example.SecRole.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. 
Jan 23, 2012 2:45:12 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads 
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. 
Jan 23, 2012 2:45:12 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads 
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. 

==== logs/stdout.log ==== 

Configuring Spring Security Core ... 
... finished configuring Spring Security Core 

Stopping Tomcat because the context stopped.
```

When I again run the same command (`grails prod cf-update`), the error message getting changed :

```
ERROR - Application 'scheduleNew' failed to start, logs information below. 

==== logs/stderr.log ==== 
Jan 23, 2012 2:52:14 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init 
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-45003 
Jan 23, 2012 2:52:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load 
INFO: Initialization processed in 379 ms 
Jan 23, 2012 2:52:14 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm setContainer 
INFO: Set JAAS app name Catalina 
Jan 23, 2012 2:52:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start 
INFO: Starting service Catalina 
Jan 23, 2012 2:52:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start 
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 
Jan 23, 2012 2:52:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory 
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
```

I really don't understand whats going on here.

What these error messages say? Where I have went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other log files. If you use the http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-cloud-foundry/docs/manual/ref/Scripts/cf-list-files.html command you can get a directory listing. Run `grails cf-list-files /` to get a listing of the top-level directory (it'll contain a `logs` and a `tomcat` directory). The `logs` directory will probably just have the stderr and stdout files that you're already seeing, but there's another logs directory under the `tomcat` directory: `grails cf-list-files /tomcat/logs`. This should have other more informative log files. Also check if there's a `stacktrace.log` in the `tomcat` directory.

Once you've found a file you want to look at, use the http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-cloud-foundry/docs/manual/ref/Scripts/cf-get-file.html command to view them, e.g.

```
grails cf-get-file /tomcat/stacktrace.log

grails cf-get-file /tomcat/logs/catalina.2012-01-24.log
```